# iAd Banner takes up unnecessary space

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, iad

I have a table view with a iAd banner at the bottom.  When I open the page in the app, the Iad expands to take up unneeded space.  I am unsure of how to get rid of this banner expansion that wastes space in my app.

[image: The blank space taken up from the table view to the iAd Banner]

Comment: it might make the tableview height smaller. Please check `tableview.frame` or `tableview.contensize` to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the storyboard and cant rap up with in the iAd and click height, so you make a constraint for the height. This way it doesn't expand upwards.